# An error when cast stdClass to array

Tags: php, arrays, casting, key

When I cast stdClass to array like this:

```
$a = (array)json_decode('{"0":{}}');
print_r($a);
print_r($a[0]); // This causes error
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

> **Notice**:  Undefined index:  0 in **[...][...]** on line
>   **3**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to pass true as second parameter in json_decode

Comment: `$a = json_decode('{"0":{}}',true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this: below is the explanation of how to use json_decod in php

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
$t = json_decode($json, true);
echo $t['c'];
```

explanation:

> **var_dump(json_decode($json));**  gives you array like this.

```
object(stdClass)[2]
public 'a' => int 1
public 'b' => int 2
public 'c' => int 3
public 'd' => int 4
public 'e' => int 5
```

To access these value.

```
$t = json_decode($json, true);
echo $t['a']; // output 1
echo $t['c']; // output 3
```

Comment: @master web this may help you :)